# PIVOT with selected MONTH()

Tags: sql, pivot

How can I pivot for a column with dates which is MONTH as the parameter?

Example:

**Data:**

```
|-----------------------------------|
| def_kstnr | def_zeit | def_datum  |
|-----------------------------------|
| 100       | 3.2      | 2011-11-02 |
| 110       | 2.8      | 2011-02-03 |
| 120       | 5.4      | 2011-11-04 |
| 130       | 2.4      | 2011-08-05 |
| 140       | 4.9      | 2011-09-06 |
| 150       | 1.5      | 2011-10-07 |
| 160       | 2.6      | 2011-12-08 |
|-----------------------------------|
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    def_kstnr,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mrz,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS Mai,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Okt,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dez
FROM
(Select 
def_kstnr,
def_zeit,
 MONTH(def_datum) as TMonth
  from
    dbo.def) source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(def_zeit)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth
```

**Result should look like this if the parameter month = 2 (February):**

```
| def_kstnr  |  Feb |
   110          2.8
```

**and if the parameter month = 11 (November)**

```
| def_kstnr  |  Nov |
   100          3.2
```

I'm already googling, but I don't know what is the keyword for this my case. I haven't find it yet. Thank you..

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL - any particular query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types. On the other hand, changing a column heading within an *application* or a *report* is usually trivial - does this have to be done in *SQL*?

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can create a dynamic sql like this

```
DECLARE @Month Int = 11,
        @MonthName VARCHAR(20),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET     @MonthName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATEADD(Month, @Month, -1), 107)
SET     @Sql = N'   SELECT  def_kstnr, 
                            def_zeit AS ' + QUOTENAME(@MonthName) + '
                    FROM    DataTable
                    WHERE   MONTH([def_datum]) = @Month'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Month INT', @Month = @Month
```

You can add your `SUM(def_zeit)` and `GROUP BY def_kstnr` to the dynamic sql if that is the result you are after.. hard to tell by your expected result